# Why isn't this flexbox with inputs working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

It's HTML inside PHP. The input boxes are just under each other. I want to position them to be in an horizontal flexbox inside a rectangle, side by side to fill the rectangle.

```css
#retang1{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1118px;
  height: 95px;
  left: 117px;
  top: 290px;

  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5FC5B7 0%, #3A857B 100%);
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 17px;
} 
    
#retang1 > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="retang1">
  <form action="enviarinfos.php" method="POST">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="materia" value="Matéria">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="trab" value="Trabalho">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="prova" value="Prova">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: set up `flex` for `form`

Comment: How do I do this, please? Do I exchange the 'retang1' for 'form'? @s.kuznetsov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your style:

```
form {
    display: flex;
}
```

And style accordingly.
You can read this link too. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Damn it would be so perfect! But it didn't work, I even tried deleting the 'flex' in 'retang1', and also setting up the '#retang1 > div' as '#form > div', but no changes, it's still one under the other... I put your code right under the #retang1 code

Comment: I also tried 'flex-direction: column;' and nothing

Comment: I only added `form { display: flex;}`  to your existing code and they are all lined up in a row. If you have another issue you can ask again.

Answer (score 2):

`display:flex` does not work for all the children elements, it sets a flex container for direct children only. That's why you have to put it inside the `form` element.

Comment: I still couldn't make it work tho

Answer (score 1):

As @Nayereh and @jakub said, you should set `flex` to the `form` element. and it works. So their answers are correct:

```css
#retang1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1118px;
  height: 95px;
  left: 117px;
  top: 290px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #5FC5B7 0%, #3A857B 100%);
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 17px;
} 
form{
  display: flex;
}
#retang1 > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="retang1">
  <form action="enviarinfos.php" method="POST">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="materia" value="Matéria">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="trab" value="Trabalho">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="prova" value="Prova">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Well you're right, this code snippet works, now I'm very confused. Trying to find the problem. Thank you so much tho.

Comment: @Carol please accept the answer of Nayereh or Jakub. They answered first.

Comment: @Carol what's the problem? It seems not to have another problem.